# How do i delete every parse column in a class?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, back4app

I want to delete every single column/object (could be both) in a class,

Im expecting to delete every column in a class and i have tried examples from back4app (my db thing) and they were very confusing.

In conclusion i want to see how to delete every column in parse.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to do that using dashboard or maybe a cloud code function?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo With a cloud code function.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a lot of differant way.

I give you some one.

You can write a module for this process. But this way very easy for you.

You can download navicat or like that..

And Open your dashboard server settings and copy mongdoDb url then paste database connection string.

And ready for everthing stuff.

run this -> `db.yourCollectionName.remove({});`

or drop collection like that -> `db.yourCollectionName.drop()`

And if you want to recreated. -> `db.createCollection("yourCollectionName")`

Everything is possible.